# Combining different variables into one new variable SAS

Tags: sas

I would like to combine different observations from different variables in one variable. The observations are all related to each other and are repeated measurements.

Example:

Current database layout.

```
**Var1    Dat1    Var2     Dat2     Var3    Dat3**
Obs1a   Dat1a   Dat2a    Dat2a    Obs3a   Dat3a
Obs1b   Dat1b   Dat2b    Dat2b    Obs3b   Dat3b
Obs1c   Dat1c   Dat2c    Dat2c    Obs3c   Dat3c
Obs1d   Dat1d   Dat2d    Dat2d    Obs3d   Dat3d
```

I want to create a new variable with combined observations:

```
Var       Dat 
Obs 1a  Dat 1a
Obs 1b  Dat 1b
....    ...
Obs 2a  Dat 2a
Obs 2b  Dat 2b
....    ...  
Obs 3c  Dat 3c
Obs 3d  Dat 3d
```

Could somebody explain me how to do this in SAS?

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 arrays of the "var" and "dat" values.  Loop through them and use the `OUTPUT` statement to create 1 observation for each value in the arrays.

```
data test;
input var1 $ dat1 $ var2 $ dat2 $ var3 $ dat3 $;

datalines;
Obs1a Dat1a Dat2a Dat2a Obs3a Dat3a
Obs1b Dat1b Dat2b Dat2b Obs3b Dat3b
Obs1c Dat1c Dat2c Dat2c Obs3c Dat3c
Obs1d Dat1d Dat2d Dat2d Obs3d Dat3d
;
run;

data test2(keep=var dat);
set test;
array v[3] var1-var3 ;
array d[3] dat1-dat3;
format var dat $8.;

do i=1 to 3;
    var = v[i];
    dat = d[i];
    output;
end;
run;
```